# store bannedwords in any file or database

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i wanna do if i execute a command like !blacklistword "word". the "word" has been saved to file or database and if someone  type the banned word from file or database then bot delete message and say 
"this word is banned".

i trying to do that with doc discordjs but still i dont know how to do that,

Comment: You can use a JSON file and the fs package to write it.

Answer (score 0):

To add a word to the blacklist: (args[0] would be the word, I assume you know how to get the word after the command)

```
var buf = fs.readFileSync("blacklist.txt");
var words = buf.toString().split("\n");

words.push(args[0]);

var output = words.join("\n");

fs.writeFileSync("blacklist.txt", output, err => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Added word to blacklist.");
});
```

To check if message has blacklisted word:

```
var buf = fs.readFileSync("blacklist.txt");
var words = buf.toString().split("\n");

var includesBadWord = false;
words.forEach(function(word) {
    if (message.content.includes(word)) {
      includesBadWord = true;
    }
});
if (includesBadWord) {
    message.delete();
}
```

Comment: i have problem to check if message is on blacklist, bot every time delete message 
even if it is not in blacklist.txt

Comment: Are you sure its because the code above? It may be caused by something somewhere else in your code.

Comment: i realy dont know, trying probably everything maybe you should give me some example how you do that?

Comment: @Rokkit could you provide some of your code so we can understand your problem?

Comment: do you have discord or line or something? I explain you what I want to do and what I have etc to not spam here or if you wanna i can type here

Comment: @Rokkit Just give us the code which doesnt work for you please. You cant just say "it doesnt work" we need to see what you have so we can check it for bugs